# CakePHP passing variables to send email with CakeEmail

Tags: email, cakephp

In CakePHP 2.x how can I create variables in a form in order to pass it to the CakeEmail function?

I currently have a php file 'email.php' that has a form with inputs 'to', 'subject' and 'message'. This form passes to a file called 'email_send.php' and I am failing to get the inputs to be passed across.

Here is the 'email.php' code;

```
<?php $this->Html->addCrumb('New Email', '#'); ?>

<div id="email_page" class="span12">
    <div class="row">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Email', array('controller'=>'person', 'action'=>'email_send.php'));
    echo $this->Form->input('To: ', array('class'=>'email_form','label'=>'To: ','value'=>$email['Person']['primEmail']));
    echo $this->Form->input('Subject: ', array('class'=>'email_form','label'=>'Subject: '));
    echo $this->Form->input('Message: ', array('class'=>'email_form email_body', 'type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Message: '));
    echo $this->Form->end('Send', array('class'=>'pull-right')); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the 'email_send.php' code. The variables $to, $subject and $message are the ones I put there assuming that I'll need to pass this function variables from the previous form.

```
<?php

$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('info@info' => 'InfoSite'))
    ->to($to)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->send($message);

?>
```

Here are the docs about CakeEmail for CakePHP 2.x;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from(array('info@info' => 'InfoSite'))
         ->to($to)
         ->subject($subject)
         ->send($message);

     ?>
```

Read My blog for sending email:

http://chetan4cake.blogspot.in/2012/07/email-in-cakephp-20.html